# Best UI framework for Highly Scalable Java Web Application

Tags: java, apache-flex, user-interface, spring-mvc, wicket

I know there is lot of similar post, But Still I am unable to decide.
We are planning to migrate a legacy web application to new framework.

Currently we have 2.5 million hits per day with less than a second average response time 
with 1000 to 1500 concurrent users.
After migration we expect 3+ million hits per day and 2000 concurrent users.

My back end will be spring/Spring JDBC(No plans to use ORM, due to complex Queries and scalability requirements)

I have shortlisted flex,Wicket and Spring MVC for frontend 
I shortlisted Flex,because our team is already working on flex Spring Blazeds based project.
and Spring MVC, because we already use lot of spring, spring security, blazeds Integration etc.
Wicket due to positive reviews in many post.

While Flex is a RIA client.  My only concern is swf file size,with high number of users, even after  spliting the flex application into modules.  It takes time to download swf.

So I think Spring MVC  is better in that case.

Wicket, I have not used, but wanted to try it out, due to lot  buzz around it.

So what would be the best UI considering the load and maintanance.

Comment: +1 for spring mvc and also, consider struts2 framework.

Comment: Check out appfuse by Matt Raible for a quick way to test various configurations and check out his blog for info regarding his findings.

Comment: What framework do you use currently ?

Comment: My company is a korean based and they have a UI framework/tool name GADIA. (I think its based on Visual stuido/VB something like that). There is no information on internet, but my korean cowrokers, gave us some training. it supports Java script etc  it is using XML to communicate with server technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to try Ext Js 4.x. It has more great UI components and its object-oriented programming logic will ease your job. For more information about ExtJS and demos:

- About Ext JS 4: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/
- Samples & Demos: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/
- And it has a gorgeous API page, you can find it here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/

And also you can find getting started guide & developer notes at its docs page...

Note: Ext JS mainly works with JSON & that makes its integration with Spring MVC very easy

Answer (score 0):

Lots of scalable choices these days.  I second the suggestion to study Matt Raible's work.

Some advice of a non-technical nature...

My experience has been that if you make a realistic list of your team's real situation, that list whittles down pretty fast.

Consider what your team already knows vs. the learning curve, what type of support you need vs. what is offered, etc.  Maybe your team is more motivated to do Flex, so that alone might make it more likely to succeed.

Don't underestimate the challenge of getting really good at a new framework.  Sure, you can get a hello world or simple demo going in no time.  Tackling all the minute details for a large-scale app is entirely another matter.  They will all fail you at some point or another, and you have to figure out a good workaround.  Note, I'm not saying don't do it, just be prepared.  One way to do that is to use it on a smaller project to get some experience.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, yes I agree with you.. what the team knows is very important thing

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of experience with Flex, having used it for a fairly large project. It's certainly a quick and easy way of creating nice looking, easy to use UIs. The problem I have with it is the need to duplicate your Java model in Actionscript code. Perhaps there is a way to bypass this; we used BlazeDS to convert between Actionscript and Java objects, which was the standard way of interaction between a Flex client and Java server at the time. It does lead to rather bloated, unwieldy codebases. We merged our client and server apps into one in order to use Maven, but you might find that you have to keep a separate Flex and Java application. To be honest, I believe that JQuery used alongside standard HTML5, JSP (and its associated technologies) and perhaps JSF would achieve all that you need for a RIA, without duplicating your business model.

I've since used SpringMVC and regard it highly, as it also frees you up to use REST. SpringMVC greatly simplifies your request/response processing logic, in my opinion.